# How to change the default background color of AlertDialog from translucent to transparent

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-alertdialog

**Want to do**

I want to change the default background color of AlertDialog from translucent to transparent.

I don't want to change the color of white place.

[image: AlertDialog image]

**What I tried**

Added **style** to **AlertDialog.Builder**. However, this code changed the background not only translucent but also white place.

styles.xml

```
<style name="TransparentDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

MainActivity.cs

```
var layout = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.dialog_eventLogOptionMenu, null);
var dlg = new AndroidX.AppCompat.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this, Resource.Style.TransparentDialogTheme).Create();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this to add this code `<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>` to your `style`. It can remove the dark in the alertdialog background.

```
<style name="TransparentDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: That code works. Thx!